# WPF with Dependency Injection using Ioc

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, ninject, ioc-container

I am currently learning how to code in WPF desktop application, and I am following this show a super old tutorial on youtube on the subject: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w5kAUCFDRy4&list=PLrW43fNmjaQVYF4zgsD0oL9Iv6u23PI6M&index=11

I have trouble using Dependency injection with multiple projects using the Ninject framework. I created a public static class called IocContainer that binds all of the required view models based on a class named application view models and gets the service of the IOC of the specific target. Snipped of the overall class is shown.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets up the Container, binds all information required and is ready for use
    /// NOTE: must be called as soon as your application starts up to ensure all services can
    /// be called.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Setup()
    {
        //Binds all required view models
        BindViewModels();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Binds all signeleton view models
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="NotImplementedException"></exception>
    private static void BindViewModels()
    {
        //Binds to a signle instance of Application View Model
        Kernel.Bind<ApplicationViewModel>().ToConstant(new ApplicationViewModel());
    }

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a serice of the IOC of the specific target 
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"> ttype to get</typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <exception cref="NotImplementedException"></exception>
    public static object Get<T>()
    {
        return Kernel.Get<T>();
    }
```

The IocContainer gets called on a overrides Onstartup function of the WPF to set up the IOC, and the application class has a Public enum variable named current age. However, when I attempt to change to a different page when running a task, it says that ApplicationViewModel
the object does not contain the definition even though it does exist. ApplicationViewModel is located in a different project named Project.Core. And I attempt to change the current page value by doing the following:

```
//Located in the Application view model
public ApplicationPage CurrentPage { get; set; }
//attempt to change the current page inside my page view model
IocContainer.Get<ApplicationViewModel>().CurrentPage = ApplicationPage.Connection;
```

Error code: Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'object' does not contain a definition for 'CurrentPage' and no accessible extension method 'CurrentPage' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found

Any ideas or suggestions?
Thanks,
Jorge Jurado-Garcia

Comment: As an example based on the nuget package [Wpf.Extensions.Hosting](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Wpf.Extensions.Hosting) have a look at [a sample project](https://github.com/SirRufo/so-76534237/tree/master)

Comment: This is not an implementation of the Dependency Injection design pattern. This is a simple Service Locator (anti-) pattern implementation. You must not pass the IoC container around or make it globally available by implementing Singleton. Instead you must use property injection or preferably constructor injection. Dependency Injection is a superior pattern to eliminate the Service Locator.

Comment: The error message clearly states that the IocContainer.Get result value is of type object and that *"object does not contain a definition for 'CurrentPage'"* property. You are obviously missing a cast: `(IocContainer.Get<ApplicationViewModel>() as ApplicationViewModel).CurrentPage = null;`. However, you should also fix your smell and implement Dependency Injection correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [service locator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern) class `Get<T>()` method returns an `object` type and not the requested type.

It should return `T`.

```cs
public static T Get<T>()
{
    return Kernel.Get<T>();
}
```